# Contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

How does one find find $$\oint_{|z|=\epsilon} z^{-1}[(z-a)(z-b)]^{1\over 2}\,\,\,dz$$ where $\epsilon>0$ is small and $a,b>\epsilon$ and real.

My initial thought was to write it as $z=\epsilon\exp(i\theta)$, but then it doesn't work because we don't get small terms so we can't expand it. I also want to use the the residue theorem. Please help!

Comment: There are branch cuts in the integrand, you have to be carefull.

Comment: ...Why did you use the word '*residue*'? Maybe because for this integral you want to use the residue theorem? Do you know **binomial series** (with noninteger exponents)? Also, do we know that $a,b\ne 0$?

Comment: Is this valid?:

To find the residue of a function $f(z)$ at $z = a$, we can look at the coefficient of $1/(z-a)$ in the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ about $z = a$. From WolframAlpha, we can find that the coefficient is $\sqrt{ab}$, and so by the Residue theorem:

$$\oint_{|z|=\epsilon} z^{-1}[(z-a)(z-b)]^{1\over 2}\ dz = 2\pi i \sqrt{ab}.$$

Do branch cuts prevent use of the Residue theorem?

Comment: @Berci: yes, thanks for correcting me. edited.

Comment: @MichaelZhao There is more to it than that. There are two branch cuts in the integrand, and one has to define them in such way that the contour $|z| = \epsilon$ can be taken. How far will the branches cancel depends on the value of $a$ and $b$, and it will alter the value of the integral.

Comment: @Henry Are $a,\, b$ real and $> \epsilon$? If so, the answer given by Michael Zhao is correct (but not the arguments, the contour **does not** encloses $a$), and it has to be justified. Tere are two cases, $a < \epsilon$, $b > \epsilon$, and $a, \,b > \epsilon\,$ (same case as $a,\, b < \epsilon$). You have to choose the branches correctly in each one.

Comment: @Pragabhava: yes, sorry for the delay, don't know why my comment didn't upload last time.

Comment: also, both a, b are greater than epsilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validity of the result holds as long as you take your branches correctly. For example, if $\epsilon < a < b$, you can take the branches (blue for $a$ and green for $b$) as

[image]

and if $a < \epsilon < b$, then you can take the branches as
[image]

In the thick part, the branches cancel, the path is well defined and you can use [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) without problems,

$$
\oint_{|z| = \epsilon} \frac{\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}}{z} dz = 2\pi i \sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}\Big|_{z = 0} = 2 \pi i \sqrt{ab}
$$

If both $a$ and $b$ are negative, the same argument applies.

**Case** $a < \epsilon$ and $b < \epsilon$

In this case, you have to take

$\hskip1.3in$[image]

and then see what happens with the small branch going from $a$ to $b$ by taking the contour

$\hskip1.3in$[image]

and make the gap of the external circle go to zero. Then the result will be the contribution of the branch plus the pole.

Comment: Excellent graphics, thanks!

Comment: @Henry I edited the answer for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b \geq \epsilon$, you can assume that $((z-a)(z-b))^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is holomophic on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq \epsilon\}$. This works because $x^\frac{1}{2}$ can be made holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{\lambda c :\lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda \geq 0\}$ for every $c$.

The integrand thus has just one pole at zero. Note that the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the laurent series expansion of the integrand around that pole is the coefficient of $z^0$ in the taylor expansion of $((z-a)(z-b))^{\frac{1}{2}}$, also around that pole, which is $(ab)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Thus, by the residue theorem, the value of the contour integral is $2\pi i (ab)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

The whole thing is a bit dubios, however, because the square root isn't a well-defined function - it's essentially a family of many functions $f$ which share the property that $f(x)^2=x$. Here, we have picked the most convenient of these functions, and computed a value of the contour integral. Whether or not another choice would have led to a different value we haven't answered.